# How can "column in different row" be placed "different column in single row"

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to group by two row and value of different two row of same column want to placed in different columns in a single row.below is my table
[image]

For example, I want no 1 & 2 row in a single row.In a single row,there will be ref_no(same in both row),by(LEDGERNAME whose VOUCHER_BY is Dr),to(LEDGERNAME whose VOUCHER_BY is Cr),AMOUNT(same in both row) or like this--
[image]

I used oracle database.How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Self join:

```
select d.ref_no,
    d.ledgername by,
    c.ledgername to,
    d.amount
from my_ledger_table d
inner join my_ledger_table c on d.ref_no = c.ref_no
    and d.voucher_by = 'Dr'
    and c.voucher_by = 'Cr'
    and d.amount = c.amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` on `REF_NO,AMOUNT`, so that `MIN` and `MAX` of `LEDGERNAME` will give you `BY` and `TO`.

Following solution should work:

```
SELECT REF_NO,min(LEDGERNAME) as 'BY',MAX(LEDGERNAME) as 'TO',AMOUNT
  FROM [yourtable]
  GROUP BY REF_NO,AMOUNT
```

Comment: What if ledgername in opposite order? That's an incorrect method of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I would go one step further to he solution by Kumar_Vikas. It appears the poster wants the "BY" column when the voucher_by is Dr and when it is Cr it should go into the column "TO".

```
SELECT REF_NO as ref_no
       ,max(case when voucher_by='Dr' then LEDGERNAME end) as 'BY'
       ,MAX(case when voucher_by='Cr' then LEDGERNAME end) as 'TO'
       ,MAX(AMOUNT) as Amount
  FROM [yourtable]
 GROUP BY REF_NO
```