# How can a single column can be shown as a row with some relationship with other column values

Tags: select, psql

I want to create a request that shows some specific values in a row showed as a column.

### - The original table:

```
**ID**      **Name**      **FRUIT**      **Description**      **Place**<br/> 
1      Jhon      Apple      Red      USA<br/> 
1      Jhon      Apple      Red      MEX<br/> 
1      Jhon      Grape      Green      USA<br/> 
1      Jhon      Grape      Green      MEX<br/> 
5      Pala      Pinap      Yello      RUSIA<br/> 
6      Aute      Pinap      Yello      CHINA<br/> 
6      Aute      Orang      Orang      USA<br/> 
8      Jess      Pinap      Red      CAN<br/> 
9      Dave      Pinap      Blue      USA<br/>
```

It is wanted to have the table in the following format:

### - Wanted result:

```
**ID**      **Name**      **FRUIT**      **FRUIT2**      **FRUIT3**      **FRUIT4**      **Description**      **Description2**      **Place**<br/> 
1      Jhon      Apple      Grape      --      --      Red      Green      USA<br/> 
1      Jhon      Apple      Grape      --      --      Red      Green      MEX<br/> 
5      Pala      Pinap      --      --      --      Yello      --      RUSIA<br/> 
...<br/>
```

A similar case is this one:
[How can "column in different row" be placed "different column in single row"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561662/how-can-column-in-different-row-be-placed-different-column-in-single-row)
But the difference in this case, is that the number of rows that are going to be changed to columns is random number not a fixed number of rows but maximum 4

i have already tried a similar way to create the view as this

```
SELECT REF_NO,min(LEDGERNAME) as 'BY',MAX(LEDGERNAME) as 'TO',AMOUNT
  FROM [yourtable]
  GROUP BY REF_NO,AMOUNT
```

in the link example

It is not changing the information from the original table

if i use the MAX or MIN in select but i have maximum 4 types of information so is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

This was solved using coalescese and an arrange of case statements to fillout the tables

BR! the talbes were not variable, it was fixed maximum 4 columns